# In a GridView, finding the row number(rowIndex) from the XPath using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xpath, dom-events

I am viewing the JSP page using Firebug in Mozilla,

```
    <tr class="header">
<tr class="even" onmouseout="low(this);" onmouseover="high(this);" style="">
<tr class="odd" onmouseout="low(this);" onmouseover="high(this);" style="">
<tr class="even" onmouseout="low(this);" onmouseover="high(this);" style="">
<tr class="odd" onmouseout="low(this);" onmouseover="high(this);" style="">
<tr class="even" onmouseout="low(this);" onmouseover="high(this);" style="">
<tr class="odd" onmouseout="low(this);" onmouseover="high(this);">
<tr class="even" onmouseout="low(this);" onmouseover="high(this);">
<tr class="odd" onmouseout="low(this);" onmouseover="high(this);">
```

When I place the mouse on one of the `<tr>`
The XPath is displayed like this

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/form/span/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]

/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/form/span/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]

/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/form/span/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]
```

My question is how can I get the value 2 from tr[2] & 3 from tr[3]  & 4 from tr[4] and so on...

Comment: [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: @JasonP I am not using jQuery. With JavaScript can I able to get that path ? tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4] such that I can parse it and can get the value 4. ?? Any method for getting the xpath to a variable ?

Comment: Oh, you have your question tagged with jQuery. In that case, I would use `var table = document.getElementById('whateverTheTableIdIs')` to select the table, then `table.getElementsByTagName('tr')` to get an array of the elements. From there, iterate them or access by index.

Comment: I am getting the object and How can I view that object? [object HTML TableRowElement] but How can I view that object ? var z = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
 var tr = decodeURIComponent(z[0].getAttribute("tr"));

Comment: I am using a onchange() function on a dropdown on a particular row, when the function is fired then I need to generate the xPath for that particular row, in which a number will be there in the path. I need to get that number[4] or [3]... depending on which row, the user is modifying.

Comment: I assume you are doing inline events? pass `this` to the function handler: `onchange="myfunction(this)"`, then your handler has a reference to the element that was changed. From there, you can traverse up to the nearest `tr`, then down to whatever other control you need.

Comment: I don't need to know about the element that was changed, I do care about the row on which I am doing the change. You said to use funtion(this), I don't understand how that will help. My question is ... When I did var z = document.getElementsByTagName('tr'); It has  [object HTMLCollection] and the length of this collection is 49.... How can iterate all those ?? and find the last value ??

Comment: I assumed that you needed a reference to an element in the same row. You can iterate the object like you would any other array.

Comment: I will iterate but How can I view, I mean it's a object ? or how can I view ? for(int i=0;i<trs.length;i++){ trs.value it says undefined  ?? }

Comment: Yes, `tr` elements don't have a `value` attribute. Try `.innerHTML`. You could also get `td`s by getting the `tr`'s children.

Comment: Jason I am getting the tr elements in the entire page.. I just need the tr for that particular row ... I think XPath for that particular row will be appropriate.